# Error on configuring Devstack compute nodes: Service n-net is not running

Tags: openstack, devstack

While installing Devstack on a compute node in a multi-node devstack lab environment error encountered: Service n-net is not running.
The local.conf file has localrc as:

```
    HOST_IP=192.168.42.12 # change this per compute node
    FLAT_INTERFACE=eth0
    FIXED_RANGE=10.4.128.0/20
    FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=4096
    FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.42.128/25
    MULTI_HOST=1
    LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
    ADMIN_PASSWORD=labstack
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=supersecret
    RABBIT_PASSWORD=supersecret
    SERVICE_PASSWORD=supersecret
    DATABASE_TYPE=mysql
    SERVICE_HOST=192.168.42.11
    MYSQL_HOST=$SERVICE_HOST
    RABBIT_HOST=$SERVICE_HOST
    GLANCE_HOSTPORT=$SERVICE_HOST:9292
    ENABLED_SERVICES=n-cpu,n-net,n-api-meta,c-vol
    NOVA_VNC_ENABLED=True
    NOVNCPROXY_URL="http://$SERVICE_HOST:6080/vnc_auto.html"
    VNCSERVER_LISTEN=$HOST_IP
    VNCSERVER_PROXYCLIENT_ADDRESS=$VNCSERVER_LISTEN
```

Please help me removing this error. 
P.S: I must use nova-net and not neutron for interaction between the controller and the compute nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Ocata release I founded a solution (2-node setup). An import part is the placement-api since the Newton update (14.0.0), so first of all enable this in all your nodes:

local.conf:

```
enable_service placement-api
```

First run ./stack.sh on your controller node and after that installation run it on the other nodes. 
Also here you will see the error Service n-net is not running...

Now edit your nova.conf file in /etc/nova/nova.conf because there will be no database and database_api section:

```
[database]
connection=mysql+pymysql://root:DB_PASS@IP_OF_CONTROLLER_NODE/nova

[api_database]
connection=mysql+pymysql://root:DB_PASS@IP_OF_CONTROLLER_NODE/nova_api
```

When adding these, you can check if it works with following command:

```
stack@jerico-02:/devstack$ nova-manage --debug host list
host                        zone           
0.0.0.0                     internal       
jerico-03                   internal       
jerico-02                   nova
```

Also in the dashboard the new compute (hypervisor) shows up!

Hope it helps!

(Tested on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS with devstack and OpenStack Ocata)